# Why can't I read the value of a cookie over a normal browser request except Ajax in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I set a cookie over Ajax, but I cannot read it's value in a view; which I am able to do over Ajax.

This is happening on Laravel 5.8.

So, basically, in routes/web.php I have this function:

```
Route::get("/sample", function () {
  echo \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::get('verified_cli');
});
```

And in routes/api.php basically the same function:

```
Route::get("/sample", function () {
  return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::get('verified_cli');
});
```

The one from api.php has value but the other does not.

Here is the code I use in a middleware to set the cookie (in Ajax):

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
    $response = $next($request);
    return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('verified_cli', $value, 900));
}
```

I want to be able to set the cookie over Ajax and be able to read it in a view as well as Ajax. Currently, I can only read the cookie value on Ajax.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be a cookie host problem? For example `api.yourdomain.com` vs `www.yourdomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The cookie has to be encrypted if you set it over Ajax, especially if you want it to be accessible over web. This worked for me.

Some middleware that is called by Ajax:

```
return response('another response')->
       cookie("some_cookie", \Crypt::encryptString("Some cotent"), 100);
```